# Does a float3 in a constant buffer secretly add padding?

Tags: c#, directx, padding, hlsl, sharpdx

I have a cbuffer in my shader.fx file, like so:

```
cbuffer lights : register (b1)
{
    float4 Light1Color;
    float3 Light1Direction;

    float4 Light2Color;
    float3 Light2Direction;

    float4 Light3Color;
    float3 Light3Direction;
}
```

I had some issues filling this cbuffer from my code, it ended up being an array of the following struct:

```
struct Light
    {
        public Color4 Color;
        public Vector3 Direction;
        //For whatever reason the constant buffer that we fill with this 
        //light must have a bytesize that is a multiple of 16, so we add a float (4 bytes)...
        public float padding;
        public static int SizeInBytes = (4 * 4) + Vector3.SizeInBytes + 4;
}
```

I wrote the array into the cbuffer by using a DataStream(SharpDX). This DataStream was NOT happy when I didn't have the padding in my struct, but this padding is not there in my shader.
The resulting lights are correct, which to me means that this padding float that has been written is either ignored, or secretly added in the shader.fx during compilation.

Which one of those is true? If any?

Comment: Maybe this is explanation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx `Each structure forces the next variable to start on the next four-component vector.`

Comment: @alex-farber Yes, this seems to be the explanation, it's a bit strange that it happens at all but I'm sure there are reasons.

Comment: The same alignment is used in OpenGL, this is for better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: 'Packing Rules for Constant Variables' (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509632(v=vs.85).aspx)

> ... Additionally, HLSL packs data so that it does not cross a 16-byte boundary. Variables are packed into a given four-component vector until the variable will straddle a 4-vector boundary; the next variables will be bounced to the next four-component vector.

You could pack some components into 'unused' space with the `packoffset` modifier. However, this doesn't fit your data structure very well. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607358(v=vs.85).aspx).